# Task notification not send

Tags: task-list

How can I automatically send a notification if someone assigns a task to me? For some websites it is working but not for new ones. The assigned person is allowed to view the list. What do I need to configure in order to get the standard notification mail send?

(During my research I found solutions regarding Release change, problems with outgoing mail but this does not fit to our problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you go into advanced settings for the list and select "Send email when ownership is assigned"?